# Two polymorph any object cast in a row with same choice

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, polymorph

If two polymorph any object (PAO) spells are cast in a row with the same end result what happens? PAO is unlike all the other polymorph spells in that your type actually changes. So for the duration what type is used? Your current type from the first PAO spell or the type that you were before PAO was cast?

Comment: The goal is to use an intermediary step to up the duration to permanent, right?

Comment: Are you targeting yourself, a living creature, or an object? What are you polymorphing this thing into?

Comment: @JKimball that is correct, the goal is to increase the duration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The duration is based on the target's original state, not it currently transmuted state, as per [spell's description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object/):

> The duration of the spell depends on how radical a change is made from the **original state** to its transmuted state.

Keep in mind that the target is not fundamentally a new creature/object, they are still the original target, but with a spell effect on them. So if [dispel magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) is cast on the target, the effect disapears, even if the duration of the transformation was *permanent*.

[Your creature type is not changed by any of the polymorph spells](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kina?Do-polymorph-spells-change-creature-type). A spell that target's animals would not work on you if you are polymorphed into a bear, because your creature type is still *humanoid*. A rock polymorphed into a tree or dog still [cannot be target of the Awaken spell](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2t4i4?What-happens-if-I-polymorph-into-an-animal#1).

Also, the [polymorph subschool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation) rules say that you cannot be under the effects of two polymorph at the same time. If that happens, you pick one to take effect:

> You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time. If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), **you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you**, taking the place of the old spell. In addition, other spells that change your size have no effect on you while you are under the effects of a polymorph spell.

Comment: You wont be under the effect of two at once, you will be under the effect of one which should influence the duration of the second. Im basically seeing it as a reduction of power requirements for the change.

Comment: @Fering I think the key is that you aren't going from original shape > shape 2 > shape 3, you are going original shape > shape 2, then original shape > shape 3. Each polymorph spell affects you individually and independently, as ShadowKras quoted.

Comment: I can't agree with the first argument in this answer. It's almost certainly *right*, but I can't agree with it. See, the term "original state" isn't actually defined anywhere in the rules; While you *can* reasonably interpret it as being a synonym for "true form" (or "the form it has when not influenced by magic"), you can *also* plausibly interpret it as "the state a thing is in prior to this specific casting of this spell." (I'm pretty sure you're right about which meaning the authors intended, but RAI arguments aren't accepted here.) I think your second argument stands alone, though.

Comment: GMJoe im going by what is said (similarly) on the transmutation school, where it uses "original form" a couple of times on a similar meaning.

Comment: Also, if one effect removes the previous one, and we would have to assume that the second spell would fail if your original state is no longer the same, because you couldnt be targeted by it otherwise. But i see your point, i will come up with more evidence for either.